# Closed form of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n k^{1/i}$ or asymptotic equivalent when $n\to\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, summation, closed-form

Is there a "closed form" for $\displaystyle S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n k^{1/i}$ ? (I don't think so)

If not, can we find a function that is asymptotically equivalent to $S_n$ as $n\to\infty$ ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cesaro (particular case of the [Stolz-Cesaro theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)) says 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}a_n=a\quad\Rightarrow \quad \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^na_i}{n}=a .
$$
I assume $k>0$ and $k\neq 1$ (as $S_n=n$ is trivial if $k=1$). Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}k^\frac{1}{n}=1$, we get
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nk^\frac{1}{i}}{n}=1\quad\Rightarrow\quad S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nk^\frac{1}{i}\;\;\sim\; n.
$$ 
I doubt there is a closed form. But we can go further in the asymptotics. Recall that if $a_n\sim b_n$ and if $b_n $ is (eventually) positive with $\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}b_i$ divergent, then $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\sim \sum_{i=1}^nb_i$. That's again Stolz-Cesaro if you want. Now by first derivative of $k^x$ at $0$
$$
k^\frac{1}{n}-1\sim\frac{\ln k}{n} \quad\Rightarrow\quad S_n-n=\sum_{i=1}^nk^\frac{1}{i}-1\sim\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\ln k}{i}=\ln k\cdot  H_n\sim\ln k\cdot \ln n
$$
where $H_n$ is the $n$th [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). Hence
$$
S_n=n+\ln k\cdot\ln n+o(\ln n).
$$

Going up to the second derivative of $k^x$, we get
$$
k^\frac{1}{n}-1-\frac{\ln k}{n}\sim \frac{(\ln k)^2}{2n^2}.
$$
So the resulting series converges and therefore, using $H_n=\ln n +O(1)$,

> $$
> S_n-n-\ln k \cdot H_n=O(1)\quad\Rightarrow\quad S_n=n+\ln k\cdot \ln n+O(1). 
> $$

Comment: Nice work (+1).  It'd be interesting to see a plot of $|S_n-n|$ vs $\log{n}$ for different values of $k$.

Comment: Note that with your second idea one can go as far as one wants in terms of the expansion.

Comment: @RonGordon Thank you, Ron. That would take someone with better computing skills than mine...

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I did my best with this simple idea, I think.

Comment: Thanks! Where can I learn that stuff? (I'm a high school student)

Comment: @user72870 Good question. I used [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem) for asymptotics of $k^\frac{1}{n}$ and [Stolz-Cesaro theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) to transfer these asymptotics (note that I could have directly jumped to the last step where I use the second derivative, and then it does not require Stolz-Cesaro). I am sorry, I don't know a reference in English which is both elementary and covers Landau's notation, equivalents, and Stolz-Cesaro. Hopefully someone will see your comment and help.

Answer (score 1):

Just note that, for $k>1$

> $$ \displaystyle S(n,k)=\sum_{i=1}^n k^{1/i} \sim \int_{1}^{n}k^{1/x}dx$$
>
> $$=-\ln(k)\Gamma(0, -\ln(k))-k+\ln(k)\Gamma\left(0, -\frac{\ln(k)}{n}\right)+nk^{1/n}
> \longrightarrow (1),$$

where $\Gamma(s,x)$ is the [upper incomplete gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function). For the other case $k<1$

> $$ \displaystyle S(n,k)=\sum_{i=1}^n k^{1/i} \sim \int_{0}^{n}k^{1/x}dx= n{k}^{1/{n}}+\ln  \left( k \right) \Gamma \left( 0,-{\frac{\ln\left( k \right) }{n}} \right) \longrightarrow (2).$$

Here is a numerical example for $k=0.2$ and $n=2000$ the sum is

> $$ 1988.361173. $$

and the approximation using $(2)$ is

> $$1987.851634. $$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n k^{\frac{1}{i}}=n+\ln(k)\ln(n)+\gamma\ln(k)+\sum_{r=2}^\infty\frac{\zeta(r)\ln(k)^r}{r!}+O(\frac{1}{n})$$

Comment: Proof? `:)`  I'd love to see where this one came from...